# videojs disable black background

Tags: html, video

videojs (v3.2.0) always shows a black background, when loading the video in swf mode. 
Does someone know how to change that?

You can add swf params like that to the player:

```
var params = {};
params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
params.wmode = "transparent";
```

*V*.options.flash.params = params;

With wmode = "transparent" you can see a black box in the top left corner. 
On IE7/8 the box does not disappear when playing the video and shows up as a black line around the video (like a black border-top).

Many thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ahh I just found this:
http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1220-black-square-in-flash-file

there it is recommended to compile the swf yourself with flash builder. you can download the project here: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js-swf

Then you can set your own swf with custom background color like that:

```
var params = {};
params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
_V_.options.flash.swf = "videojs/VideoJS.swf";
_V_.options.flash.params = params;
```

hope videojs will soon update their selfhost-download and the CDN with a proper swf included.
cheers,
Florian

Comment: What file do you put these settings in?

Comment: Ok, i figured it out.  You actually don't need to compile your own SWF at all.  Just putting these settings when loading VJS is sufficient.