# Unwanted border appearing on video element

Tags: css, video

I'm trying to get rid of the border around this video http://bit.ly/ZihaJV The idea is that the video plays on a white background with no borders. The problem might be due to the ratio of the video and the size of the player.

I also found this post but it doesn't solve the problem. I don't even have access to Flash to compile the swf. [videojs disable black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845839/videojs-disable-black-background)

Using a  with a white border around the video to hide the black lines appearing might be a work around but I run into a problem because the video needs to be responsive.

The actual webpage shows more borders than this testing one. Sorry but I can't show the original.

Thanks and any help will be welcome.

Comment: Not a chance of me clicking on that link. It could be anything. Don't use URL shortners

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Sorry Liam, I read the post you linked just now. Fair enough, I didn't post the full url so the company's name wouldn't be exposed. Also, I couldn't post the code because I wasn't sure which was the problematic area i.e. swf, js, css or html. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's probably the parameters you are sending to the SWF object. Would you edit in the object HTML snippet (plus any JS that interacts with it)? This is a good idea since that shortlink will presumably break in the near future, once you remove the dev site from your server. However, we want questions here to last!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the video you linked to, the border line along the top of the video is part of the video file itself, so it's an issue with the original file or the way you edited it. (I often have this problem with videos. Quite annoying.)

A quick visual fix with CSS would be to pull the top of the video up a bit and hide the line at the top:

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
    top: -2px;
}

.video-js {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But yeah, that's a little cheeky.

Comment: Oh thanks Ralph! that's a very good solution, it would certainly fix the problem. The key is to use overflow: hidden; and also some margin tweaking to hide the borders.

Comment: Just gonna add my 2 cents - for my (video.js 5) all I had to do was hide the background color of the video-js (made it transparent).

Comment: you actually blow up the video what could cost you quality and then you remove actual stuff from the video, pure loss. It's very easy to solve with the following: *:focus {
    background: none;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

Comment: No, it wasn't a :focus issue. The line was part of the video content, so the real solution was to redo the video.

Answer (score 0):

The way I finally sorted out following ralph.m comments is as follow:

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
  /* make the video larger so it can hide*/
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  /* displace video to hide*/
  left: -5px;
  /* allow space for hiding*/
  margin: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.video-js {
  /* make sure overflow is hidden*/
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```