# Removing black border on video box in html (using <video> tag)

Tags: video, tags

Could anybody advise me how to remove the black border around the box in which the video is displayed on the homepage of http://yasawahomestays.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by setting the CSS style for video tag:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your css. Change the names though:

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
top: -2px;
}

.video-js {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Credits to : [Unwanted border appearing on video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853203/unwanted-border-appearing-on-video-element)

Comment: Thanks, but I am very new in this. In the case of my website, what names should I put instead of those in your example?

Comment: I think its just your video element in html. Add just those classes to the video html element.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

```
 clip-path: inset(0px)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.